# Oracle Table Logging

Tags: oracle

I have a scenario where I would like to know about a particular table in a database as what applications are accessing it to identify the dependency of applications (more than one java project) on this particular table.

Is there a way I can turn on a log feature on a particular table in the database to get more information about that table only, The information I am looking for is dependency on this table (as what applications use this table in their code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out Oracle dependencies you can leverage metadata tables.

- To find out table dependencies - `dba_dependencies`
- To find foreign key constraints - `dba_constraints`

Comment: Note that the `dba_XXX` views are usually not accessible for regular users. You should rather use the `ALL_XXX` or even `USER_XXX` views